# dictionary and array looping with elements

Tags: objective-c, ios

I got a dictionary with 10 arrays and each array got 20 elements. How can i access the 18th element of an each array? pointers please. Thanks. Attaching my log file[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (NSString *key in [dictionary allKeys])
{
    NSArray *menuList = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    NSString *imageName = [menuList objectAtIndex:17];
    NSLog(@"Image Name:%@", imageName);
}
```

It seems what you actually wanted was

```
NSString *imageName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"episodeImagePath"];
```

Comment: I actually didn't know that existed. With it being a mapping I'd always accessed values using keys. It feels a little unusual that it's moving away from the dictionary structure.

Comment: Heh, everyone seems to be forgetting that arrays are zero based today ^^

Comment: James, but i wanted to access 18th element of each array?

Comment: @JamesWebster I attached the log file, i still cant figure out how to access the 18th element of each array

Comment: NSLog(@"menuList :%@", menuList); menulist is an array

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? I've amended my answer, is that what you were after?

Comment: by using [menuList object At Index:17], i can just acces the element of 1st array, but i want 18th element of each array

Comment: Are you looking to put each of these elements into another array for use later?

Comment: basically the element at that place is an image i want to populate that on a view, with tags for views

Comment: What is your dictionary variable name?

Comment: Could you run the code I've posted and show me what it prints.

Comment: it is not printing anything to the log

Comment: Then it sounds like your dictionary isn't anything. Try NSLog(@"Dictionary :%@", dictionary) before that for loop

Comment: Remove the for loop and replace the NSLog(@"Dictionary :%@", dictionary)  with the new code

Comment: Image Name: (null) is the log

Comment: Thank for the help James, I figured it out, as menulist was a array, i took the object at index and stored in another array

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
//iterate all values
for (NSArray *arr in yourDictionary.allValues) {
    //To loop the array
    for (NSString *str in arr) {
       NSLog(@"Element %@", str);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh right then instead of 18 set 17 (forgot that its 0 based sorry :) )

Comment: Omar, I meant was, how can i loop trough each array?

Comment: still cant figure out, I attached my log file, menulist is an array with elements, i want 18th element of each array.

Answer (score -1):

i think its better to take one object class, so that we can get all 18th elements in one array

Comment: attached the log file can you have a look please.